What is the first Sci-Fi/Fantasy film to include adverts for fake films with real actors?
A scene in Jurassic Park: The Lost World, includes adverts for three films that have been made up for the scene.

Jack and the Behnstalks starring Robin Williams
Tsunami Sunrise starring Tom Hanks
King Lear starring Arnold Schwarzenegger



What is the earliest film to include adverts for fake movies, using real actors?

I don't know about the first, but The Last Action Hero (1993) memorably has an advert for the Terminator starring Sylvester Stallone.

Back to the Future 2 had Jaws 19 directed by "Max" Spielberg.

You may be interested in Films in Films.

Although more of a spoof movie The Kentucky Fried Movie (1977) than full SF/F (ridiculous/silly - thus fantasy - premises) it incorporated at least trailers/adverts for fake movies / tv shows. One of which was That's Armageddon with named actors.

A parody of the then-common disaster film genre, with Donald Sutherland as the clumsy waiter and George Lazenby as the architect




Other spoof trailers included:

Catholic High School Girls in Trouble
Cleopatra Schwartz
Danger Seekers

...although these did not have named real actors

I always assumed they got look alikes, but wow that really was George Lazenby and Donald Sutherland! And, uhh... Jack Roberts. But "Barbara Radnitz" (the nurse) is Victoria Carroll.

John Landis's Schlock (1973) features voiced advertisements for two movies both titled See You Next Wednesday starring real actors.
@8:10

Be sure to watch the dinnertime movie tonight at 6 on 6.
Tonight it's See You Next Wednesday starring Charles Laughton, Claudette Colbert, and Mickey Rooney. A fun filled musical frolic through the leper colonies of Europe during the Thirty Years War.

@25:02

Tomorrow evening's dinnertime movie at six on six. Tomorrow evening's film is See You Next Wednesday starring Jimmy Stewart, Donna Reed, and "Stymie" Beard in an action-packed war drama  of defrocked missionaries in the Belgian Congo.


See You Next Wednesday became a running gag in films involving Landis being mentioned in Kentucky Fried Movie (1977)...

...and a full billboard in The Blues Brothers (1980) starring Donald Sutherland.

...and many more.

Airplane II from 1982 had a Rocky XXXVIII poster with Rocky as an old man when Sonny Bono was buying his bomb.  Probably not the first but pretty funny.

(And made by the same team as the earlier The Kentucky Fried Movie, as in another answer.)

Mel Brookes' fantastical and farcical 1981 History of the World, Part I features a 'trailer' for a film History of the World, Part II featuring a segment titled 'Hitler on Ice' (later featuring a space opera segment titled 'Jews in Space').



